# How to type a button with react-router-dom Link in MUI v5

Tags: reactjs, typescript, material-ui

### Problem

I am migrating from MUI v4 to v5 and I am having an issue using the `styled` function to style a `Button` component. For some reason, when I use `MyButton` instead of `Button`, the compiler has an issue with the `component` prop.

### Error Message

```
Type '{ children: string; component: <S = unknown>(props: LinkProps<S> & RefAttributes<HTMLAnchorElement>) => ReactElement<any, string | JSXElementConstructor<any>> | null; to: string; }' is not assignable to type 'IntrinsicAttributes & { children?: ReactNode; classes?: Partial<ButtonClasses> | undefined; color?: "inherit" | "primary" | ... 5 more ... | undefined; ... 9 more ...; variant?: "text" | ... 2 more ... | undefined; } & ... 5 more ... & { ...; }'.
  Property 'component' does not exist on type 'IntrinsicAttributes & { children?: ReactNode; classes?: Partial<ButtonClasses> | undefined; color?: "inherit" | "primary" | ... 5 more ... | undefined; ... 9 more ...; variant?: "text" | ... 2 more ... | undefined; } & ... 5 more ... & { ...; }'.
```

### My Code

```
import { alpha, Button, styled } from "@mui/material";
import React from "react";
import { Link, HashRouter as Router } from 'react-router-dom';
import "./styles.css";

export default function App() {

  const MyButton = styled(Button)(({ theme }) => ({
    color: 'white',
    margin: theme.spacing(1),
    backgroundColor: alpha(theme.palette.common.white, 0.25),
    '&:hover': {
      backgroundColor: alpha(theme.palette.common.white, 0.35),
    },
  }));

  return (
    <Router basename="/">
      <div className="App">
        <MyButton component={Link} to="/"> // why doesn't this work?
          My Button
        </MyButton>
      </div>
    </Router>
  );
}
```

### CodeSandBox

[CodeSandbox Link Here](https://codesandbox.io/s/weathered-glitter-p7nr1?file=/src/App.tsx)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You're missing the props type definition of the `Link` component. To fix it, install `@types/react-router-dom` package and declare your HOC props type when using `styled` like this:

```
import { Link, HashRouter as Router, LinkProps } from "react-router-dom";

const MyButton = styled(Button)<LinkProps>(({ theme }) => ({
  // your link styles
}));
```

```
<MyButton component={Link} to="/route">
  My Button
</MyButton>
```

### Live Demo

[image: Codesandbox Demo]

Comment: Unfortunately, this doesn't work anymore with recent dependency updates; see CodeSandbox here: https://codesandbox.io/s/69420620-how-to-style-a-button-with-react-router-dom-link-in-mui-v5-component-prop-problem-6pfvjn?file=/src/App.tsx

Comment: As of react router dom 6 `@types/react-router-dom` must not be installed anymore, as the types are now integrated and the last separate type package is 5.x.

Answer (score 1):

This seem to work for me

```
import { Link as RouterLink } from 'react-router-dom';
import { Link} from '@mui/material';
```

...

```
<Link 
    to={slug}
    component={RouterLink}
    variant="button"
    color="secondary"
    >
Read More
</Link>
```